# Display mysql data in divs instead of table

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, ajax

Hi Im developng an hotel search website where client can search for hotel... I have developed my backend where hotel can update the details into my database... now im stuck with my front end where client can see my database based upon there search criteria. In php i do know how to display data in in table but unable to get my head stright in html div... I want to understand would i can display database instent of table... What all the coding required to get such resulte... Please click on my below link and you would understand how i want to display in result

http://hotel.makemytrip.com/makemytrip/site/hotels/search?session_cId=1388679988524&city=BOM&country=IN&checkin=01042014&checkout=01062014&area=South%20Mumbai&roomStayQualifier=1e0e&type=&sortName=

```
<div class="offset-2">
                        <div class="col-md-4 offset-0">
                            <div class="listitem2">
                                <a href="images/items/item7.jpg" data-footer="A custom footer text" data-title="A random title" data-gallery="multiimages" data-toggle="lightbox"><img src="images/items/item7.jpg" alt=""/></a>
                                <div class="liover"></div>
                                <a class="fav-icon" href="#"></a>
                                <a class="book-icon" href="details.html"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8 offset-0">
                            <div class="itemlabel3">
                                <div class="labelright">
                                    <img src="images/filter-rating-5.png" width="60" alt=""/><br/><br/><br/>
                                    <img src="images/user-rating-5.png" width="60" alt=""/><br/>
                                    <span class="size11 grey">18 Reviews</span><br/><br/>
                                    <span class="green size18"><b>$36.00</b></span><br/>
                                    <span class="size11 grey">avg/night</span><br/><br/><br/>
                                    <form action="http://demo.titanicthemes.com/travel/details.html">
                                     <button class="bookbtn mt1" type="submit">Book</button>    
                                    </form>         
                                </div>
                                <div class="labelleft2">            
                                    <b>Mabely Grand Hotel</b><br/><br/><br/>
                                    <p class="grey">
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum nec semper lectus. Suspendisse placerat enim mauris, eget lobortis nisi egestas et.
                                    Donec elementum metus et mi aliquam eleifend. Suspendisse volutpat egestas rhoncus.</p><br/>
                                    <ul class="hotelpreferences">
                                        <li class="icohp-internet"></li>
                                        <li class="icohp-air"></li>
                                        <li class="icohp-pool"></li>
                                        <li class="icohp-childcare"></li>
                                        <li class="icohp-fitness"></li>
                                        <li class="icohp-breakfast"></li>
                                        <li class="icohp-parking"></li>
                                        <li class="icohp-pets"></li>
                                        <li class="icohp-spa"></li>
                                    </ul>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: We will help you troubleshoot, but we can't troubleshoot none existant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple as you do it using the tables. Tables are used only because they already formatted so the output is clear means you can display different data in different rows by using  or different columns using

You can also print the data in the divs same things as you follow in a table. If you have problems using the divs go through some tutorials for divs or you can still do it using the tables just give it proper styling using CSS.